# Motherboard not lighting up when PSU is switched on

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, power

I have an `ASRock Fatal1ty Z370 Gaming K6` motherboard which is a quite recent board. While I was using my computer, everything shut down rapidly. At first, I thought it was a power blackout in the house but the other appliances seemed to work. I then realised that the computer was refusing to boot up.

I thought that it was the power supply but after removing it, I was able to successfully power on an older computer that drew less power. The power supply is a 750W `Corsair RM750X`. I disconnected all hard drives, M.2 SSDs and memory DIMMs and decided to test the motherboard with the CPU and power supply separately. I also used a working 450W power supply to test the motherboard but unfortunately, the same results were evident. A video of the problem is available [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ASdFauVlQ85Elep4D0E96msVYf7qJOLS).

As soon as I flick the switch on the power supply, the motherboard lights up briefly before dying again. The on-board power button also refuses to work. If it may help, the BIOS was updated a week earlier but updated perfectly fine since the computer was being used normally and functioning normally before this incident occurred. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try a different PSU to rule this out completely. If you get the exact same symptoms with a known working PSU then I'd consider an RMA to the manufacturer if it's under warranty.

Comment: @Kinnectus I tested out another power supply. It was a 450W power supply. The motherboard acted the same, it lit up and then just dies. I should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Edit the question with this new test and result. Obviously the next thing the manufacturer might try to wriggle out of: is your processor known working? I also note from your video you haven't put the heatsink, thermal paste and fan on the CPU... a tad risky, eh?

Comment: @Kinnectus Keep in mind the I wasn't turning on the system. When the power supply is turned on, the motherboard is supposed to light up which indicates that current is flowing through the motherboard. It has been doing this for the last 6 or 7 months. If the lights don't turn on, that means there's a problem somewhere within the motherboard since both power supplies managed to power on a different system.

Comment: Sounds like might be time to contact the place you bought it from (if it's under warranty) and begin a return.

Comment: @Kinnectus In terms of the CPU, I am unsure if it is working as I can't test it in any other machine. It is an `Intel Core i5-8400`.